# Browsing a docker container in windows 10

Tags: node.js, docker, windows-10

I created an image using docker for windows and deployed it locally but I get an error that a certain file cannot be found. It is probably a problem with the build so I thought I'll see the container's files to solve this problem and avoid any future problems.

I tried running powershell on the docker using

```
docker run -it node-web-app powershell
```

But I get an error

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from 
daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting 
container process caused "exec: \"powershell\": executable file not found in 
$PATH": unknown.
```

Anyone has any experience with this and can point me in the right direction?

My docker file :

```
# Create container with node and npm preinstalled
FROM node:latest

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Bind to port 8080
EXPOSE 8080

# Run the server
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start-prod" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dockerfile` states that you have built your image from `node:latest`.
Now if you go to the docker hub, at https://hub.docker.com/_/node/, you will see the details of the `node:latest` image.

This will take you to https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/9023f588717d236a92d91a8483ff0582484c22d1/9/Dockerfile.

In this `dockerfile` you will see that it is built from `buildpack-deps:jessie`.
Basically this is a `debian` image which means it will not have powershell.
And hence as @fly2matrix pointed out the error very clearly states that there was no executable called `powershell` in the `PATH` variable inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that **Powershell** executable is not available in your container.
I assume that your base image is Linux and not windows.
Look for Dockerfile's FROM statement.

Could you please share your Dockerfile to be sure on the real problem ?

Comment: I added my docker file contents